# How to implement a "History" Back-Button

Tags: javascript, php, browser-history, html5-history, referer

I have a website showing the details of a client (`www.mysite.com/client.php?id=1234`). 
This page can be loaded from different locations within the website.

I want to have a "Back-Button" to the previous page.

My first solution was to use `<a href="javascript:window.history.back();">back</a>`. This is working generally fine.

But of cause, the client's details can be edited (by an bootstrap modal). Once "save" is pushed, the data are stored and the client's details (`www.mysite.com/client.php?id=1234`) are loaded again to show the correct (updated) data. Now the above solution doesn't work fine anymore as the "Back-Button" needs to be pushed twice to get to the "entry"-site.

Questions:

1) Is the JavaScript-Solution the correct one, or do I have to implement a server-side array to track the history-log (sounds quite heavy)?

2) Is anything wrong with the reload of the site after update? Or can I prevent a client-side history-log in that case?

3) Any other ideas?

Thanks for your support!

Tim

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History/pushState

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The back button normally brings the user back to the previous URL. The browser may cache the page contents and show outdated data. You could tell the browser not to cache specific pages.

```
<meta http-equiv="Cache-Control" content="no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate" />
<meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache" />
<meta http-equiv="Expires" content="0" />
```

Furthermore, any user-specific solution will fail if one user is modifying the data and another is just viewing it. You must force fetching the data from server every time a page is loaded. Hence, no-cache headers

UPDATE:

To bring users back where you want, you could use another parameter specifying the "back" destination URL. E.g.

```
 www.mysite.com/client.php?id=1234&backdestination=list.php%3Fshow%3D123 
 //list.php?show=123
```

then, on the page create a button/link and use the value from `backdestination`

UPDATE 2:

You could check `window.History` API and specifically `replaceState` method. It technically allows you to specify where "back" is. 
However, you still need to carry the `backdestination` URL across requests. Either via GET parameter, a session variable, or localstorage.

Perhaps you could generalize the implementation by always storing the history of last X URLs. Then, if you need to modify the back destination, use some kind of algorithm to determine where users came from. E.g. take the user to the last URL where the script file name is not the current one:

history of requests:

```
 /list.php
 /list.php?page=2
 /client.php?id=123     // User viewing the client
 /client.php?id=123     // Page reload after POST
```

Now, if a user clicks back, the same client.php is loaded. However, you can create a generic script that modifies the History object with [`replaceState()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History/replaceState).

I hope this gives you some ideas.

Comment: Thanks for your proposal and recommendations, but I have implemented these headers already. I'm not sure, if your answer suits to my question. I don't have an issue with outdated data because the browser has fetched the data. The data needs to be reloaded and it works fine. My issue is the "double" click on the back-button to get to the entry point. Any other ideas?

Comment: Thanks for the update. This comes close to what I tried already, but stopped that approach, because I hoped to find an easier way. The issue with this is that I have to post ```backdestination``` as a variable in the html-form during the edit/update-process, carry it through the controller and treat it while reloading the page. And this for every form (there is not only ```client.php```).

Comment: Thanks for update2. Yes, I could try building a stack-array in ```$_SESSION```. Thanks for the tip.